# Не виден модуль numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, импорт, python-3.9

ОС  Ubuntu
Стоит  python 3.9

Команда

```
import numpy
```

дает сообщение

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

При этом в Synaptic'е он установлен
И команда

```
sudo apt-get install python3-numpy
```

тоже говорит, что модуль есть

Что с этим делать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: У вас может быть несколько питонов в системе. Убедитесь, что вы запускаете именно тот питон, в который установлен `numpy`